# match SSN anywhere in line without leading or trailing dash

Tags: regex

I can match an SSN using:

```
\b\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}\b
```

It easily matches:

```
123-45-1234
```

or

```
John Doe SSN# 123-12-1235
```

The problem is it will also match:

```
100-123-45-1234-99
```

or

```
1010-23-3--123-23-1234-56-712
```

The dash is not recognized as part of a word boundary.  I can't use ^ as the SSN sometimes is in a sentence or has leading whitespace. - the SSN doesn't always start at the beginning of a line.

I am at a loss.

I have tried using \A but it does not appear to work

```
\A\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}
```

matches only

```
123-45-1234
```

does not match:

```
John Smith, SSN, 123-45-1234
```

I basically need to catch exactly the string of digits and dashes for an SSN anywhere in a line except when it has a leading or trailing dash.

I have been testing this in rubular.com and cannot find a solution.  All of the solutions I can find relate to using the ^ to identify the start of the line or \A but this breaks what I need it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below regex would looks for the numbers in this format `xxx-xx-xxxx` are present just after a space or starting point and followed by a space or end of a line. ,

```
(?<=\s|^)\b\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}\b(?=\s|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rJ6gZ3/2)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\s|^)` Look-behind is used to look just after to a space or starting point.
- `\b` Matches between a word and non word character.
- `\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}` NUmber format. It must be xxx-xx-xxxx
- `\b` Matches between a word and non word character.
- `(?=\s|$)` Look-ahead is used to check whether the one which follows the number would be a space or line end.

Comment: Thank you!  I cannot upvote this yet because I need at least 15 reputation.  This solution worked perfect.  I have included some additions to it and the final result looks like:

Comment: you need 2 more reps. haha :-)

Comment: yep, you could tweak my regex :-)